# .net DateTime formatting hide time if midnight?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

I'm working on formatting datetime's to display on a graph, and its working great so far.  I have the format string:

M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

and it prints as I'd like it to except the following:  I want to completely hide the HH:mm:ss if the time is midnight.

Is it possible to do without a custom iformatprovider?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just check for midnight and change the format string to "M/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: Unless you have a very large amount of data I find it unlikely that you would many if any entries which happened on midnight when rounded to the nearest second. If you do though surely just showing the date does not tell the user enough information to let them know it happened at midnight especially if viewed without context e.g. on it's own

Comment: It was graphing a very large amount of data. Hundreds of thousands of points.  What I want to format is the X axis labels, most of the times they're rounded its from midnight to midnight, but when you zoom in, you need the H:M:S.  The microsoft charts package im using allows for a single format string to be entered.  Unfortunely, I don't think I can get the format I want that way, and will have to add some custom code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now; 
string txt = time.ToString(time == time.Date ? "M/dd/yyyy" : "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I will prolly end up using this.  Its not a perfect solution (the microsoft charts package doesn't allow selective formatting without adding extra code), but I think its the best solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now; 

string format = "";

if (time.Hour == 0) 
{
   format = "M/dd/yyyy";
} 
else 
{
   format = "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
}
```

Comment: This will hide the time at for example "00:12:34".

Comment: @Carra: That was the point of the original question.. to hide the time at midnight.

Comment: 2 minutes after midnight is not midnight but the time will be hidden it too. I check midnight with "time == time.Date".

Answer (score 3):

A culture-independent version of the solution proposed by @JDunkerley would be:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string txt = time.ToString(time == time.Date ? "d" : "g");
```

More about standard date and time format strings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution is not a very good one because it does not take into account user's localized time format, and simply assumes `US English`.

Here's how it should've been done:

```
public static string formatDateTimeWithTimeIfNotMidnight(DateTime dt)
{
    //RETURN:
    //      = String for 'dt' that will have time only if it's not midnight

    if (dt != dt.Date)
    {
        //Use time
        return dt.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //Only date
        return dt.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```